# Building R under windows without tcltk

Tags: r

Is it possible to disable building the tcltk package when building R from source on windows? I only use the cli and the tcltk dependency makes the deployment more complex.

Comment: (1) tcltk itself is included in R.  You don't need to access an external tcl tk install so its not more complex to deploy. (2) Also tcl tk is not just tk but also tcl and tcl can and is used by many command line packages.  Removing tcltk will cripple your version of R. (3) Finally you could just use the pre-built R Windows build.  There is no need to build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. (1) I did not find any tcl directory in the source code I downloaded. (http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-2/R-2.11.1.tar.gz). It was causing the compile issue. My understanding by reading the documentation is that you need to have a tcltk distribution if you want to build R. (3) According to Dirk I don't need to compile R to do what I need (building c++ extensions) so I am glad I can use a pre-built version.

Comment: I think I got it. You need tcltk to compile R but not to deploy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is. Look at `./configure --help`.

There is also an entire manual devoted to [R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html) which has an entire section devoted to [Installing R under Windows](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Installing-R-under-Windows).

Lastly, R does come prebuilt for 32 and 64 bit Windows so maybe you don't even need to build from source?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I plan to use Rcpp to integrate a couple of C++ functions. My impression is that I need to be able to compile R from source to do that. How do you run the configure script from windows?

Comment: I commented out the line #define HAVE_TCLTK 1 in src/gnuwin32/fixed/h/config.h. Did a clean rebuild but still have the same problem.

Comment: No, to use Rcpp you need the Rtools installed *to build R packages from source*.  You definitely do **not** have to rebuild R to use Rcpp.

Comment: I see. I am glad to hear it. I am going to try to do it. Regarding the original question, which is not relevant anymore, it looks like it can be done but it is not encouraged. Anyways, thanks for your help.